# Runtime Error 201 после считывания двух чисел в Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Программа в FPC. Компилируется нормально, при запуске после ввода первых двух чисел программа вылетает с рантайм ошибкой 201. Вот код программы.

```
{$H+}
program lanterns;


var
        lamps,substr:String;
        lampCount,events,maxSegCount:LongInt;
        c,i,j:LongInt;
        state:Char;
        done:Boolean;

function isDone(l:String):Boolean;
var
        isDone_i:LongInt;
begin
        for isDone_i := 1 to lampCount do
        begin
                isDone := false;
                if l[isDone_i] = '0' then
                        break;
                isDone := true;
        end;
end;
function max(a,b:LongInt):LongInt;
begin
        max := a;
        if b > a then
                max := b;
end;
function min(a,b:LongInt):LongInt;
begin
        min := a;
        if b < a then
                min := b;
end;
function countSegs(str:String):LongInt;
var
        segSize, countSegs_i:LongInt;
begin
        countSegs := 0;
        for segSize := 1 to lampCount do
        begin
                for countSegs_i := 1 to lampCount-segSize+1 do
                        if pos('0', copy(lamps, countSegs_i, min(countSegs_i+segSize-1, lampCount))) = 0 then
                                countSegs := countSegs + 1;
        end;

end;
begin
        read(lampCount, events);
        read(lamps);
        maxSegCount := 0;
        done := isDone(lamps);
        for c := 1 to events do
        begin
                read(i, j, state);
                for i := i to j do
                        lamps[i] := state;
                if not (done) then
                        done := isDone(lamps);
                if done then
                begin
                        writeln((lampCount * lampCount + lampCount) div 2);
                        continue;
                end;
                maxSegCount := max(maxSegCount, countSegs(lamps));
                writeln(maxSegCount);
        end;
end.
```

Comment: Для поиска ошибок в программе придуман отладчик, в котором можно выполнять программу по шагам, смотреть значения переменных и найти строку кода, в которой возникает ошибка или исключение. Запустите свой код в отладчике и скажите из какой строки кода "вылетает" ошибка.

Comment: Результат функции isDone никогда не будет True. Возможно ошибка возникает из-за этого.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> countSegs := countSegs + 1;
> ```

Проблема здесь, при инициализации паскаль пытается вызвать функцию, но вы не передаете значений в нее.

```
countSegs := countSegs(string) + 1;
```

Comment: Вроде бы ему надо не вызывать функцию, а просто увеличить результат на единицу.

Comment: -1. Попытки вызова функции тут нет. Паскаль разрешает использовать имя функции вместо `Result`.

Comment: исправив на мое решение все работает работает. + если попробовать запустить на abc pascal то ошибка "не хватает параметров"

Comment: Kromster, да, знаю что он хочет на единичку больше сделать. Просто указал на ошибку